# CMU Sphinx Windows binary Crashes

Tags: cmusphinx

When I try to run CMU Sphinx (0.8 32bit) on Windows with the following command:

```
pocketsphinx_continuous.exe 
-hmm E:\Program\Development-Resourses\Audio\SpeechToText\pocketsphinx-0.8-win32\pocketsphinx-0.8-w
in32\model\hmm\en_US\hub4wsj_sc_8k 
-lm E:\Program\Development-Resourses\Audio\SpeechToText\pocketsphinx-0.8-win32\pocket
sphinx-0.8-win32\model\lm\en_US\hub4.5000.DMP 
-dict E:\Program\Development-Resourses\Audio\SpeechToText\pocketsphinx-0.8
-win32\pocketsphinx-0.8-win32\model\lm\en_US\hub4.5000.dic 
-infile ShortPodcast.wav
```

It stuck on the line `INFO: tmat.c(205): Reading HMM transition probability matrices` and then crashes.

I tried it for `wsj0vp.5000.DMP` and `cmu07a.dic` with no success.

Log:

```
INFO: cmd_ln.c(691): Parsing command line:
E:\Program\Development-Resourses\Audio\SpeechToText\pocketsphinx-0.8-win32\pocketsphinx-0.8-w
_continuous.exe \
        -hmm E:\Program\Development-Resourses\Audio\SpeechToText\pocketsphinx-0.8-win32\pocke
\en_US\hub4wsj_sc_8k \
        -lm E:\Program\Development-Resourses\Audio\SpeechToText\pocketsphinx-0.8-win32\pocket
n_US\hub4.5000.DMP \
        -dict E:\Program\Development-Resourses\Audio\SpeechToText\pocketsphinx-0.8-win32\pock
\en_US\hub4.5000.dic \
        -infile ShortPodcast.wav \
        -rawlogdir log

Current configuration:
[NAME]          [DEFLT]         [VALUE]
-adcdev
-agc            none            none
-agcthresh      2.0             2.000000e+000
-alpha          0.97            9.700000e-001
-argfile
-ascale         20.0            2.000000e+001
-aw             1               1
-backtrace      no              no
-beam           1e-48           1.000000e-048
-bestpath       yes             yes
-bestpathlw     9.5             9.500000e+000
-bghist         no              no
-ceplen         13              13
-cmn            current         current
-cmninit        8.0             8.0
-compallsen     no              no
-debug                          0
-dict                           E:\Program\Development-Resourses\Audio\SpeechToText\pocketsph
0.8-win32\model\lm\en_US\hub4.5000.dic
-dictcase       no              no
-dither         no              no
-doublebw       no              no
-ds             1               1
-fdict
-feat           1s_c_d_dd       1s_c_d_dd
-featparams
-fillprob       1e-8            1.000000e-008
-frate          100             100
-fsg
-fsgusealtpron  yes             yes
-fsgusefiller   yes             yes
-fwdflat        yes             yes
-fwdflatbeam    1e-64           1.000000e-064
-fwdflatefwid   4               4
-fwdflatlw      8.5             8.500000e+000
-fwdflatsfwin   25              25
-fwdflatwbeam   7e-29           7.000000e-029
-fwdtree        yes             yes
-hmm                            E:\Program\Development-Resourses\Audio\SpeechToText\pocketsph
0.8-win32\model\hmm\en_US\hub4wsj_sc_8k
-infile                         ShortPodcast.wav
-input_endian   little          little
-jsgf
-kdmaxbbi       -1              -1
-kdmaxdepth     0               0
-kdtree
-latsize        5000            5000
-lda
-ldadim         0               0
-lextreedump    0               0
-lifter         0               0
-lm                             E:\Program\Development-Resourses\Audio\SpeechToText\pocketsph
0.8-win32\model\lm\en_US\hub4.5000.DMP
-lmctl
-lmname         default         default
-logbase        1.0001          1.000100e+000
-logfn
-logspec        no              no
-lowerf         133.33334       1.333333e+002
-lpbeam         1e-40           1.000000e-040
-lponlybeam     7e-29           7.000000e-029
-lw             6.5             6.500000e+000
-maxhmmpf       -1              -1
-maxnewoov      20              20
-maxwpf         -1              -1
-mdef
-mean
-mfclogdir
-min_endfr      0               0
-mixw
-mixwfloor      0.0000001       1.000000e-007
-mllr
-mmap           yes             yes
-ncep           13              13
-nfft           512             512
-nfilt          40              40
-nwpen          1.0             1.000000e+000
-pbeam          1e-48           1.000000e-048
-pip            1.0             1.000000e+000
-pl_beam        1e-10           1.000000e-010
-pl_pbeam       1e-5            1.000000e-005
-pl_window      0               0
-rawlogdir                      log
-remove_dc      no              no
-round_filters  yes             yes
-samprate       16000           1.600000e+004
-seed           -1              -1
-sendump
-senlogdir
-senmgau
-silprob        0.005           5.000000e-003
-smoothspec     no              no
-svspec
-time           no              no
-tmat
-tmatfloor      0.0001          1.000000e-004
-topn           4               4
-topn_beam      0               0
-toprule
-transform      legacy          legacy
-unit_area      yes             yes
-upperf         6855.4976       6.855498e+003
-usewdphones    no              no
-uw             1.0             1.000000e+000
-var
-varfloor       0.0001          1.000000e-004
-varnorm        no              no
-verbose        no              no
-warp_params
-warp_type      inverse_linear  inverse_linear
-wbeam          7e-29           7.000000e-029
-wip            0.65            6.500000e-001
-wlen           0.025625        2.562500e-002

INFO: cmd_ln.c(691): Parsing command line:
\
        -nfilt 20 \
        -lowerf 1 \
        -upperf 4000 \
        -wlen 0.025 \
        -transform dct \
        -round_filters no \
        -remove_dc yes \
        -svspec 0-12/13-25/26-38 \
        -feat 1s_c_d_dd \
        -agc none \
        -cmn current \
        -cmninit 56,-3,1 \
        -varnorm no

Current configuration:
[NAME]          [DEFLT]         [VALUE]
-agc            none            none
-agcthresh      2.0             2.000000e+000
-alpha          0.97            9.700000e-001
-ceplen         13              13
-cmn            current         current
-cmninit        8.0             56,-3,1
-dither         no              no
-doublebw       no              no
-feat           1s_c_d_dd       1s_c_d_dd
-frate          100             100
-input_endian   little          little
-lda
-ldadim         0               0
-lifter         0               0
-logspec        no              no
-lowerf         133.33334       1.000000e+000
-ncep           13              13
-nfft           512             512
-nfilt          40              20
-remove_dc      no              yes
-round_filters  yes             no
-samprate       16000           1.600000e+004
-seed           -1              -1
-smoothspec     no              no
-svspec                         0-12/13-25/26-38
-transform      legacy          dct
-unit_area      yes             yes
-upperf         6855.4976       4.000000e+003
-varnorm        no              no
-verbose        no              no
-warp_params
-warp_type      inverse_linear  inverse_linear
-wlen           0.025625        2.500000e-002

INFO: acmod.c(246): Parsed model-specific feature parameters from E:\Program\Development-Reso
cketsphinx-0.8-win32\pocketsphinx-0.8-win32\model\hmm\en_US\hub4wsj_sc_8k/feat.params
INFO: feat.c(713): Initializing feature stream to type: '1s_c_d_dd', ceplen=13, CMN='current'
INFO: cmn.c(142): mean[0]= 12.00, mean[1..12]= 0.0
INFO: acmod.c(167): Using subvector specification 0-12/13-25/26-38
INFO: mdef.c(517): Reading model definition: E:\Program\Development-Resourses\Audio\SpeechToT
pocketsphinx-0.8-win32\model\hmm\en_US\hub4wsj_sc_8k/mdef
INFO: mdef.c(528): Found byte-order mark BMDF, assuming this is a binary mdef file
INFO: bin_mdef.c(336): Reading binary model definition: E:\Program\Development-Resourses\Audi
-0.8-win32\pocketsphinx-0.8-win32\model\hmm\en_US\hub4wsj_sc_8k/mdef
INFO: bin_mdef.c(513): 50 CI-phone, 143047 CD-phone, 3 emitstate/phone, 150 CI-sen, 5150 Sen,
INFO: tmat.c(205): Reading HMM transition probability matrices
```

Comment: And what is the stack trace of the crash?

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev No log generated, only I see this in EventViewer: Faulting application name: pocketsphinx_continuous.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x50c9da0f
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.3.9600.17031, time stamp: 0x5308893d
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0001f0a3
Faulting process id: 0x14c8

Comment: Where did you download the binary, did you compile it yourself?

Comment: From CMU Sphinx sourceforge project. It was binary from scracth

Comment: Probably it failed to create rawlogdir, could you try without that argument?

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev, no difference, same crash while running `bin\Debug\pocketsphinx_continuous.exe -hmm model\hmm\en_US\hub4wsj_sc_8k -lm model\lm\en_US\hub4.5000.DMP -dict model\lm\en_US\hub4.5000.dic -infile ShortPodcast.wav`